# Ack & negative lookahead giving errors

Tags: linux, command-line, ack

I have a problem with using `ack-grep` with a negative look ahead.

I am running this command:

```
ack-grep "paypal_responded(?!_at)"
```

but I am getting the error:

```
bash: !_at: event not found
```

I have tried adding backslashes in various places, but I'm also new to using ack & linux, so please treat me as a newbie with any instructions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `ack-grep 'paypal_responded(?!_at)'`

You need single-quote to avoid bash interpret `!` as history expand command.

Comment: Great stuff.  That's sorted it.  Thanks  :o)

Comment: @TobyG Would you mind to accept this as an answer so that this question no longer remains unanswered? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry.  This dates back to my early days on here  didn't realise I'd not accepted an answer.  Done now.

Comment: This also works with zsh. It is way more practical than escaping all `( )` and `!` in regular expressions

Answer (score 4):

The shell is interpreting the `!` in your input as a command substitution:

```
$ ack-grep root /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
$ !ac
ack-grep root /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
$
```

You need to tell the shell that `!` has no special meaning; there are two ways to do that:

```
ack-grep "paypal_responded(?\!_at)"
```

```
ack-grep "paypal_responded\(?\!_at\)"
```

or

```
ack-grep 'paypal_responded(?!_at)'
```

Single-quoted strings have fewer transformations applied to them:

```
$ ack-grep "s\!" /etc/passwd
$ ack-grep 's!' /etc/passwd
$
```

Comment: I tried...
ack-grep "paypal_responded(?\!_at)"
.. but got the error...
"ack-grep: Invalid regex 'paypal_responded(?\!_at)':
  Sequence (?\...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/paypal_responded(?\ <-- HERE !_at)/"

Comment: Sheesh, there's obviously more going on than I expected -- my simple examples worked exactly as I wanted, but the longer one with `(?!_at)` fails in horrible ways and it's easy to see why you were driving yourself nuts trying to make it work. `ack-grep "paypal_responded\(?\!_at\)"` works fine.... but I can't explain it.