# How to exclude lines with regexp

Tags: regex, grep

I have a list of lines with numbers. Need to exclude from it all lines starting with `373`.

For example my list is:

```
37322433151
37323175491
19376717186
79684480273
97246000252
37323175491
37323175491
40745108277
```

If i do `cat ... | egrep '^[^373].*'`, then it excludes lines that start from `3` or `7`, the output is

```
19376717186
97246000252
40745108277
```

Even if expression is `^[^(373)].*`

I need too exclude only if line starts with `373`. Could anyone tell me what expression should be used ?

I also tried `'^(?!373).*`

Comment: For the look-ahead option, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197814/regex-lookahead-for-not-followed-by-in-grep).

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna do it with a regex then you can try:

```
^(37[^3]|3[^7]|[^3])[0-9]+$
```

Comment: @ЕгорГрижук You are welcome. If this solves your problem then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `grep -v`:**

```
grep -v "^373" file
```

**Using awk:**

```
awk '!/^373/' file
```

**Use `grep -P` (PCRE): Negative Lookahead**

```
grep -P '^(?!373)' file
```

Comment: Ninja'd by 13 seconds

Comment: @Foon: lol :) was wondering why no obvious answer came for 5 minutes and then 2 arrived in within 13 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a solution, the regexp will not be used with grep, it will be used in billing, to match numbers. Need a regexp, that excludes, not a key in grep

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `regexp will not be used with grep, it will be used in billing`. Don't you need a grep solution?