# Is it possible to perform look behind and look ahead assertions in grep without perl support?

Tags: regex, awk, grep

Like vi perhaps?

My perl equivalent is:

```
grep -Po '(?<=^.L.........\s).*(?=\s->\s)' rsync_itemized.log
```

Which finds all the symlink modifications and outputs the filename part. Obviously, I can use awk:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^.L........./ { print $2 }' rsync_itemized.log
```

But I was wondering if greps native regex engine supports it.

Comment: Apparently not, per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9198987/1681480), which you probably already saw.

Comment: Hadn't seen that, no.  I actually wrote some unit tests using the -P option, but since the unittest started to run tests that could potentially remove things from the root file system, I switched to using a chroot for the environment the software will run in.  That, unfortunately had no grep without perl support.  So I was merely looking for a cheap way to change my existing expressions without having to change much else.  Thanks though.

Comment: I see. Can you install things in chroot? `ack` grep apparently will do look-aheads.

Comment: Not trivially, since its unpacked from an image built somewhere else.  I'll use `awk` since I have that available.

Comment: ack is specifically designed to be able to be installed as a single text file.  You can download the single Perl program and put it anywhere on your system you want.  See http://beyondgrep.com/install/ for details.

Comment: But then you might as well use Perl directly.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

- `grep -P` uses [libpcre](http://pcre.org/), a compiled library (written in C, not perl) that is perl-*compatible*
- Your `awk` command won't work if there is a space in the file name

This `sed` command will work a little better:

```bash
sed '/^.L......... /!d; s///; / -> .*/!d; s///'
```

This deletes all lines that do not match the first regex, then removes the matching portion of the remaining lines, then does the same for the second regex, leaving you with the text in the middle.  Since regexps are [greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap), the second regex will turn `a -> b -> c` into `a` even though you wanted `a -> b`, so this isn't a perfect solution either.

Perhaps you can use `perl` directly (I assume you're on a system for which `grep` was compiled without the libpcre library and therefore can't do `-P` but perhaps you still have access to `perl`):

```bash
perl -ne '/^.L.........\s(.*)\s->\s/ and print "$1\n"'
```

This time, greediness works in our favor (regexps are evaluated left to right) and you'll correctly extract a file named `a -> b` that is symlinked to `c`.

If you have [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) (nearly any Linux system), you can mimic that logic:

```bash
sed '/^.L.........\s\(.*\)\s->\s.*/!d; s//\1/'
```

But I haven't technically answered your question, which was about using `grep` without `-P`.  `grep` uses [basic and extended POSIX regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) (BRE and ERE).  Even ERE can't do what you're looking for, so the quick answer is that you cannot do this in a single `grep` command without `-P`.  You might be able to do it with multiple `grep` commands, but it would be extremely ugly and I'm leaning on saying you actually cannot do it without look-arounds or text replacement, neither of which are available in BRE or ERE.