# Using grep to find matches of a string without a specific character at the end

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to use grep to find non-plural instances of a particular string.

For example, I want to find all instances of "string", but leave out any instances of "string**s**".

How can I do this?

Edit: I do want to find instances that are followed by other characters. I literally just need to leave out the ones that end in 's'

Comment: To make answerers can easily figure out your problem, please ad some example with expected result.

Comment: You should get rid of the text about finding non-plurals since that's an extremely difficult problem given cases like `octupus/octopi`, bus/busses` and `sheep/sheep`. Just keep your question focused on what you want - to delete words that end in `s` so, for example, `bus` will be deleted even though singular and `octopi` will remain even though plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word boundaries in `grep`:

```
grep '\<string\>' file
```

Examples:

```
# with word boundaries
grep '\<string\>' <<< $'string\nstrings'
string

# without word boundaries
grep 'string' <<< $'string\nstrings'
string
strings
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on comments below you can use:

```
grep -E '\<string([^s]|$)' file
```

**Example:**

```
grep -E '\<string([^s]|$)' <<< $'string\nstrings'
string
```

Comment: The tricky thing (sorry for being unclear) is that I am looking for special characters. This is in a python script, so I am looking for instances that have a colon, left brace, new line, etc. I literally just need to leave out instances that end in 's'

Comment: Yep! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\b` to match [a word boundary](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html). Hope this helps:

```
[root@rh57quinn ~]# echo 'find instances of a particular string - any "string", but leave out "strings" and drawstring' |grep -Eo '\bstring\b'
string
string
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a general `grep` you can done it in this way

```
echo "stringsMystring1string2strings" | grep -Eo 'strings?' | grep -Eo '^string$'
```

The idea is you just list all strings by using both pattern `string` and `strings` first, by

command:

```
`grep -Eo 'strings?'`
```

results:

```
strings
string
string
strings
```

The grep the result again by

command:

```
grep -Eo '^string$'
```

result:

```
string
string
```

And according to [regex-lookahead-for-not-followed-by-in-grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197814/regex-lookahead-for-not-followed-by-in-grep), some people suggest to use `GNU grep` where you can use an option `-P` or `--perl-regexp` to enable `lookaround` feature. A given regex might take form like this

```
echo "stringsMystring1string2strings" | grep -P 'string(?!s)'
```