# grep character not followed by character

Tags: linux, unix, grep, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to print lines that have `b` not followed by `e` in a file. I tried using negative look-ahead, but it's not working.

```
 grep  'b(?!e)' filename
 grep '(?!e)b)' filename
 egrep  'b(?!e)' f3.txt
```

When I run these commands, nothing shows up, no error or anything else. I checked other people's similar posts as well but was unable to run it.

Comment: `grep "b[^e]" filename.txt` might do it? Or with `'` on Linux. What if you use `grep -E` for extended regex support?

Comment: From this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/9198987 lookarounds are not supported in standard grep, but in GNU grep, `grep -P` might use Perl compatible regexes and support it.

Answer (score 14):

`grep -E 'b([^e]|$)' filename`

That should match 'b' followed by a character which is not 'e', or 'b' at end-of-line.

Answer (score 2):

If your grep supports Perl regular expressions with `-P`, look-arounds work:

```
$ grep -P 'b(?!e)' <<< 'be'     # Gets no output
$ grep -P 'b(?!e)' <<< 'bb'
bb
$ grep -P 'b(?!e)' <<< 'b'
b
```

The only difference to `grep -E` (in this case) is that you don't have to take care of the end-of-line situation (see [pilcrow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784607/3266847)).