# Grep multiple strings

Tags: linux, grep

I want to find a list of files that have A but do not have B and C.

`grep -r -L 'B\|C'` finds the ones without B and C, but how do I add the condition of having A as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
grep -l "A" $(grep -r -E -L "B|C" *)
```

i.e. search for files containing "A" in the list of files that your original command generates.

Comment: This one also returns a list still with either `B` or `C` in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [negative lookahead in `grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197814/regex-lookahead-for-not-followed-by-in-grep) using options `-P` or `--perl-regexp`

```
grep -r -P -L '^(?!.*A).*$|B|C'
```

Comment: For some reason it still gives me a list with `B`

Comment: you can remove `-l` option and show me match string

Comment: It brings back a list that has `A` but it doesn't check if it has either `B` or `C`

Comment: Ex. `template.jsp:<%@ include file="/includes/navigation_lower.html" %>`

Comment: Sorry. `lower.html` is `A`. The whole list only shows lines with `A`

Comment: That's what I did. The full command is `grep -r -P '(?!.*(DetVehicle|customer))lower\.html(?!.*(DetVehicle|customer))'`

Comment: try with `grep -r -P -L '^(?!.*lower\.html).*$|DetVehicle|customer'`

Comment: Hm that's odd. It works, but for some reason it also returned an empty file that I have here. When I made a new empty file, it did not return it. Either way, it works. Thanks!

Comment: Changed to Mark's answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do it like this:

```
grep "A" file.txt | grep -v -e "B" -e "C"
```

The first `grep` finds lines containing `A`, the second `grep`takes the result and removes lines containing either "B" or "C". This works by the `-v` flag which inverses matches.

Comment: I ran `grep -r -l "lower\.html" | grep -v -e "DetVehicle" -e "customer"` and it return a list of files that have `lower` but they also have either `Vehicle` or `customer`