# POSIX BRE syntax for a negative look ahead/not followed by

Tags: regex, posix

I'm trying to create an email validation with some exclusions. Basically, ignore email addresses with this format, filtering out all City Governments and Schools:
`user@ci...us` and `user@..[a-z]{2}.us`

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34625320/7606730) mentions negated character classes [^], alternation |, and the end of string anchor $. How can I rewrite the following, which works without any look ahead?

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+<@[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+?\.+[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+?\.(us|info|to|br|bid|cn|ru)
```

Using a few of the regex validators this works using a standard look ahead:

```
(?!.*\@ci\..+?\.us$)(?!.*\@*\..+?\.ca.us$)([a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+?\.+[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+?\.(us|info|to|br|bid|cn|ru)
```

My first attempts led me to this solution which only partially handle the 1st look ahead (I tightened the top level domain with the word boundary `\b`:

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+<@([^c"][^"]+|c[^i"][^+]+|ci[^i"][^i"])[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+?\.+[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+?\.(\bus\b|\binfo\b|\bto\b|\bbr\b|\bbid\b|\bcn\b|\bru\b|\bu\b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I could get but it gets me there:

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+<@([^c]+|c(c|ic)+([^ic]|i[^c][^ic]))+(c(c|ic)+(i|ic))+?\.+[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+?\.(\bus\b|\binfo\b|\bto\b|\bbr\b|\bbid\b|\bcn\b|\bru\b|\buss\b|\bbw\b|\bu\b)
```

To clarify I was looking to exclude [Locality domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us#Locality_domains) & Affinity Namespaces for public school districts. The above will exclude `something@ci.subdomain.us` (as well as spam-prone TLD's ending in `.info|to|br|bid|cn|ru|uss|bw|u`), but as it turns out the email addresses from those usually have 4 levels/parts, e.g., `info@ci.boston.ma.us`. [This blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808143528/http://www.osrd.org/projects/grep/negation-in-regular-expressions) gave me a clue.